# Преобразование символов в с#

Tags: c#

научите плз новичка преобразовывать символы строки в другие регистры. Допустим имеется строка

```
String str = "Карл у Клары крал кораллы";
```

Как теперь сделать так, чтобы все символы "а", к примеру, стали в верхнем регистре?
Вариант

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if(Char.Equals(str[i], 'а'))
        Char.ToUpper(str[i]);
}
```

почему-то не работает
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вариант не работает, потому что вы просто вызываете функцию и никак не используете возвращаемый ею результат. Делать нужно скажем вот так:

```
    str = str.Aggregate("", (current, t) => current + (t == 'а' ? 'A' : t));
```

Comment: благодарю за наводку

Comment: Пожалуйста. Справедливости ради, если вы в C# совсем новичок и с LINQ не знакомы, то ответ? который дал @Макс Жуков (без учета опечаток) вам подойдет больше

Comment: Если через LINQ, то может лучше всё же

    str = string.Concat(str.Select(t => (t == 'а' ? 'A' : t)));

Answer (score 3):

```
string str = "Карл у Клары крал кораллы";
str = str.Replace("a","A");
```

или

```
char[] ch = str.ToCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++)
    if(ch[i].Equals('a')
       ch[i] = char.ToUpper(ch[i]);
str = new string(ch);
```

Comment: вы хоть проверяйте что пишете. Оба ваших кода не сработают из-за опечаток. Как не стыдно

Comment: @DreamChild, отвечая на вопрос, лучше подсказать как, а не дать источник для копипаста, разве нет?

Comment: разумеется. Но я обратил ваше внимание на сам факт, что отвечая на вопрос вы даете не выполняющий задачу код, а это очень непрофессионально. Вряд ли вы станете покупать, скажем, автомобиль в салоне, где работают хорошие, грамотные менеджеры, но вот продаваемые ими машины почему-то не ездят, разве нет?

Answer (score -1):

```
введите код здесьusing System;
```

class Program {
public static int Main() {

string str="Карл у Клары крал кораллы";
Console.WriteLine(str); //Карл у Клары крал кораллы

//переменная с большими буквами А
string strUP=null;

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) {
 //обязательно введите русскую букву "а", а не английскую
 if( Char.Equals(str[i], 'а') ) {
  strUP+=char.ToUpper(str[i]);
 }
 else {
  strUP+=str[i];
 }  
}
Console.WriteLine(strUP); //КАрл у КлАры крАл корАллы

Console.ReadKey();
return 0;
}
}

Comment: Вариант 
string str="Карл у Клары крал кораллы";
Console.WriteLine(str); //Карл у Клары крал кораллы 

str = str.Replace("а","А");
Console.WriteLine(str); //КАрл у КлАры крАл корАллы

самый правильный, нужно только ввести русские буквы "а", а не английские